# Keeping local X-Axis from rotating, while moving up and down on a Curve

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I made a Geometry Node, which transforms a given Curve into a street. While the curve has the same value vor Z, it looks fine (Picture 1).
When I start playing with the Z values tho, the road starts rotating inward. How can I keep it from doing that?
Basically, I want the Normals local X Value 0.

If possible, I want to solve that in Geo Nodes.

Thanks in advance :D

[image: While Flat]
[image: While Changed Z Value]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set **Twist method** to **Z-Up** in curve properties:

[image]

And you can use **set curve normal** in geometry nodes:

[image]

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks. Is there a way, to do that in geometry nodes tho?

Comment: I haven't found

Comment: @Kralkaz-.- Before the _Curve to Mesh_ node add in a _Set Curve Tilt_ node with 0°, this should reset all tilting in the curve. But additionally use the _Twist Method_ > _Z-Up_ in the _Curve Properties_ as well.