# How to bend & Loop geometry around a curve in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I've seen variations of this question on here but I'm looking for a solution that will integrate the correct rotation of the arrayed objects aswell as loop endlessly, the below example is exactly what I'm looking for apart from that it cuts out after the start of the curve.

Hope that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

At the moment I'm trying to combine these 2 different setups:

[is it possible to move points along curve normals (Geometry Nodes)](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/is-it-possible-to-move-points-along-curve-normals-geometry-nodes)

[how to bend geometry with geometry nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245282/how-to-bend-geometry-with-geometry-nodes/259196?noredirect=1#comment442119_259196)

[image]

Comment: Did you see this "variation of this question" and it didn't help? [Keeping local X-Axis from rotating, while moving up and down on a Curve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/256597/) //EDIT: Sorry, I thought you were looking for changing the rotation of the objects.

Answer (score 3):

add this to the x-array node:

[image]

change count to 280

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that Chris, mostly achieves the result albeit very slowly haha.. do you know the reason why that slows down the fps so much? And unfortunately it's not quite as versatile as I was hoping, whenever I change the input curve or adjust the spacing for the arrayed objects (Multiply node controlling offset in your above image) it seems to cause a hiccup in the animation. Would there be a way of combining it with this setup:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/is-it-possible-to-move-points-along-curve-normals-geometry-nodes
the looping on it was very seamless and quick!

Comment: I've been trying to crack it this afternoon but still can't figure it out...would there be a way to use the map range node to remap the values from this setup onto the spiral?
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258733/is-it-possible-to-move-points-along-curve-normals-geometry-nodes